# Create Fishnet issues with measurement distance

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, vector-grid

I am trying to create a regular soil sampling grid based upon digitised field extents.

I had posted a previous question today relating to issues with coordinate systems and displaying the sample points accurately in TM75 Irish Grid, I've now resolved this issue.

I want my soil sample points to be on a 35m grid basis.

However, when I now perform create fishnets and specify 35 for the number of rows and columns, when the points are projected into TM75 these points are now 20m apart (when measured in WGS84 these points are 35m apart).  I have been digitising and producing the gridded points (through fishnet and clip) using WGS 84 before projecting these points to TM75 in a new map document. Does the issue with distance spacing lie with WGS 84? What should I be specifying in the number of rows and columns, I can't seem to find any information on WGS 84 and fishnets.

Comment: Create Fishnet generates featured a fixed distance apart. Since the North Pole at the Prime Meridian is the same location as the North Pole at 90 E/W, it's not possible to use ground units in GCS WGS84, only angular units. If you need your objects equidistant in a projected CS, you should generate them in a projected CS.

Comment: Are you using Create Fishnet with ArcGIS Pro, with ArcMap, or with another software application?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.5, what projected CS should I use for conversion to TM75 at a later stage?

Comment: Why do you want to wait to create the fishnet in TM75 at all? Any other projection will have the same issue, just not as pronounced.

Comment: I need it to be in TM75 to sample in the field locations on a garmin gps

Comment: First remark: a line with 35 meters defined on the WGS84 datum will not measure only 20 metres when projected with Gauss-Krüger. Your report is somehow inaccurate. If you wish to create a regular grid on the Cartesian plane, your only option is to do it on the final CRS, in this case the Irish TM75.